# Trying to change a specific h1 tag into an h2 tag with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to eliminate an h1 tag by replacing it with an h2 tag using jquery. Here is the code that I want to change:

```
<div class="player-unavailable">
<h1 class="message">An error occurred</h1>
</div>
```

Pretty simple, but I haven't been able to find the answer on how to target a specific h1 tag as opposed to all h1 tags on the page.

Comment: Shows us the jQuery code in question that isn't working (that you've tried).

Answer (score 0):

You can target an element by its position on the page like so:

```
$($('h1')[idx]).replaceWith('<h2>content</h2>');
```

...where "idx" is the index of the h1 element.